# flippedCoordinates rotated chart pointMarker showing wrong place

Tags: scichart, scichart.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44y0s.png)

Points are not plotted correct on the scichart

```
xAxis.axisAlignment = EAxisAlignment.Left;
xAxis.flippedCoordinates = false;
yAxis.axisAlignment = EAxisAlignment.Top;
yAxis.flippedCoordinates = true;
const fastLineSeries = new FastLineRenderableSeries(wasmContext, {
   dataSeries: ds,
   strokeThickness: 1,
   stroke: "red"
   pointMarker: new SquarePointMarker(wasmContext, {
      width: 5,
      height: 5,
      fill: "blue",
      stroke: "blue",
      strokeThickness: 1,
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [SciChart.js Forums](https://www.scichart.com/questions/js/vertical-chart-pointmarker-showing-on-wrong-place), this issue was patched in build  1.1.1362.

You can get the latest builds of [SciChart.js over at npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scichart).